# Toggle Window Transparency With Autohotkey Mouse Hover?

Tags: mouse, windows-10, autohotkey

I'd like to obscure a windows contents, until I very quickly "peek" at it with a mouse hover, and then have it return to being obscured/transaprent/etc. when I remove the mouse from the window.

Ive looked over the web and have found some possible examples that partially do it I think, without the mouse-hover functionality, Eg. [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/20996-auto-raise-mouse-hover/) & [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/53249-transparent-andor-always-on-top/), but they don't use the hover function as I'd like. Sadly the frequency I'd be using this feature means these methods aren't very useful to me.

---

**Edit:** I found [this thread](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/79251-solved-how-to-turn-off-transparency-while-mouse-over-gui/), and have used some of the code to create a simple window that goes transparent on mouse over. It can be used above the window I need obscured. I'll post the code below. Perhaps it could be improved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code i've used as per the edit in the question.

```
WatchWin = GUIwin ; Window Title to watch.



CoordMode, Mouse, Screen

GUI, Show, w200 h200, GUIwin

SetTimer, WatchMouse, 10

Return



WatchMouse:

WinGet, WinHWD, ID, % WatchWin

MouseGetPos,,, mPosHWD,, 1

WinSet, Trans, % ( mPosHWD = WinHWD ? 150 : 255 ), GUIwin 

Return



ESC::ExitApp    ; <-- Press escape to exit.
```